# Different Versions of the same Library in maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

Is it possible to use in java program a library with two different versions ?

Maven Dependency

```
<artifactId>olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-core</artifactId>           
<version>2.0.10</version>
```

and

```
<artifactId>olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-core</artifactId>   
<version>2.0.7</version>
```

version **2.0.10** contains some features which are not available in **2.0.7** but it not supports `$filter=startswith`. 
Two versions contains same classes and interfaces

Comment: Simple answer to this is: No. Cause you have the jar files on the classpath. So this means it only depends on the order on the classpath which one will be picked. You can't have the same classes in the same packages twice within a java program. So you have to make a decision which version you will use...If something does not work with a newer version I would check the release notes of the appropriate lib or ask on the users list of the appropriate lib (or file in an issue)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly that is not a good idea as you have no control (without major effort) on which dependency will be first on the classpath. 
You will only be able to access the first found on the classpath and you might get weird errors. e.g. like MethodNotFoundExceptions and the like

Think about upgrading if at all possible.

Comment: How i can upgrade ? in version 2.0.7 the query api/v1/reports/Users?$filter=startswith(DisplayName,'mir') eq true  works fine ,but this version does not support to filter in expanded Entity.
In version 2.0.10 :api/v1/reports/Users?$filter=startswith(DisplayName,'mir') eq true  dosent work 
Error:org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: I don't know as I am not familiar with `olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-core` but my answer stands. It is a bad idea to have two versions of the same dependency in your pom. Sometimes frameworks explain how to upgrade or implement something in a different way, but that was not the question...